# How many Columns are in Print Area

Tags: vba, excel

I need half of a Table's columns to set the position of the title above them, using the following expression:

```
Cells(Range("Salary[[#Headers],[Mounth]]").row - 1, Range("Salary[#Headers]").Columns.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / 2).Formula = "= ...
```

But my table has some columns which are not within the Print Area.

I need to make sure all visible cells are in Print Area.

**Print screen**

[image]

Comment: Show images of the table and the desired print area as a starter. And do you mean all visible columns within the table?

Comment: Yes, All visible columns.

Comment: I think edit your question to make this clear and post image of how data is and what you want to see as an output.

Comment: I check the question, and upload the appropriated picture after checking the question more exact.